# arduino send hex frame using RS485

Tags: serial-port, arduino

Hi I have a leonardo and am trying to communicate with a device. I need to send the following hex code 
FF 01 AA 
I tried to store it as an array of bytes and loop through it but it doesn't seem to work. I am also expecting some reply from the device.

```
int byteReceived;
int byteSend;
int byteSentSuccessfully;
uint8_t byteToSend[3] = {
       0xFF,
  0x01,
  0xAA,

    };
   char buffer[8];
void setup()   
{
  // Start the hardware serial
  Serial1.begin(9600);

}

void  loop()
{
  byteSentSuccessfully = Serial1.write(byteToSend,sizeof(byteToSend));
  if (byteSentSuccessfully)
  {
    Serial.println("Wrote to device");

  }

  if (Serial1.available()){

    byteReceived = Serial1.readBytes( buffer,sizeof(buffer)); 
    if (byteReceived){
      Serial.println("She is talking to me");//check on com port

    }
  }
}//END OF MAIN LOOP
```

---

I also tried to send it in a characters, but no luck-

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
delay(10000);//enough time to start up my com port monitor
  String myStr = "FF0101AAAC";
  char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*myStr.length()+1);

  Serial.println("Using toCharArray");
  myStr.toCharArray(buffer, myStr.length()+1);

  Serial.println(buffer);

  free(buffer);

  Serial1.write(buffer);
}

void loop() {
 //only need to do this once

}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message or just nothing? If you have an error message you should post it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No errors, the machine is just not responding. When I send the same code using a RS485 to USB with Realterm, it works fine. So I think it has something to do with the format I am sending it in. Maybe the data sent by the Arduino using Serial is converted to ASCII? Not sure how to find this out. I am new to arduino programming but I have experience in java etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

while (!Serial1)  { }

after Serial1.begin in the setup loop?

Also, if you are trying to communicate with a device over RS485 what converter are you using?

Comment: yes, thanks. I tried if Serial1.available() then write etc. The RS485 converter I am using is the RS485 Shield DEV-11959 from sparkfun. It fits on top of the arduino and I connect the 2 wires from my device to the A&B points on the shield. I am assuming that the onboard chip will convert this RS485 data to Serial format readable by arduino and feed it into the hardware RX/TX. Maybe I am naive to assume this? Unfortunately there is not much documentation on this shield. This combined with my inexperience is turning out to be quite a challenge to overcome.

Comment: That shield does send the converted serial to the Tx/Rx pins. Have you tried to send the your hex numbers using Serial.write() instead of Serial.print()?

Comment: Yes, I used Serial1.write() - as in my code above-
    Serial1.write(byteToSend,sizeof(byteToSend));
I also tried to loop through the array in a for loop and write 1 byte at a time.